# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type RelayCommand Model

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, relaycommand

the following is my code and I did include both `System.Linq` and also `System.Data`, and I still get this error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type RelayCommand Model

I've searched all over the websites for quite a while and still couldn't find anything that was even remotely useful. Any suggestion will be very appreciated.

```
class MainViewModel:ViewModelBase
{


    private string _location;
    private bool   _agree;
    private MyRelayCommand _relayCommand;
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _relayCommand = new MyRelayCommand(
            new Action(() => Install()),
            () => true);
    }

    public void Install()
    {

    }

    public string Location
    {
        get { return _location; }
        set
        {
            if (_location == value)
                return;

            //RaisePropertyChanging(() => Location);
            _location = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Location);

            _relayCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

        }
    }

    public bool Agree
    {
        get { return _agree; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _agree)
                return;
            //RaisePropertyChanging(() => Agree);
            _agree = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Agree.ToString);

            _relayCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

        }
    }


    public ICommand InstallCommand
    {
        get { return _relayCommand; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The expression you provide isn't a valid action. It expects the expression after `() =>` to return a `string`, not another `Action`.

Try this:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => Agree.ToString());
```

Or if you are using Prism:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => Agree);
```

I expect though, that `RaisePropertyChanged` expects the name of the property which has changed, so maybe you just need:

```
RaisePropertyChanged("Agree");
```

You could decorate `RaisePropertyChanged` with the .NET 4.5 `CallerMemberName` attribute, so you don't even need to provide the property name changed.

```
RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string callerMember = null)
{ }
```

Then call it from `Action`:

```
RaisePropertyChanged();
```

Comment: RaisePropertyChanged (RPC) might come from `Prism` in which case it should be `RaisePropertyChanged() => Agree);` instead. Although, the question is lacking some information about the `RPC` method..

Comment: @Default: Thanks. That is possible indeed.

Comment: Actually, by looking at the `Location` property that is probably the case, compare it with `RaisePropertyChanged(() => Location);`

Comment: @Default: Thanks. Updated with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Include below namespace in your code :
using System.Data.Entity; It should solve your issue.